# Error when install Skype on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, skype, xubuntu

I download and install Skype on Xubuntu 20.04 I use this command

```
sudo apt install -f ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

But got this error:

```
sudo apt install -f ./skypeforlinux-64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'skypeforlinux' instead of './skypeforlinux-64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatomic1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatomic1 skypeforlinux
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/88,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 298 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Xubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

I have tried to install libatomic1 from the ISO file but not sucess. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

it was just apt repsitory list issue. In file xxx it begin with line:

```
deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)]/ focal main multiverse restricted universe
```

I add a # to comment it:

```
# deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)]/ focal main multiverse restricted universe
```

then it can get the file from online repository and it work.